# How to open Dashboard Screen after the Splash Screen

Tags: android

How to open dashboard right after the splash screen, once the account has been logged in but not logged out?

Below is my splash screen code:

```
public class ActSplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    ProgressBar progress;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_act_splash_screen);

        progress=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progress) ;

        Handler handler=new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Intent obj=new Intent(ActSplashScreen.this,CustomerLoginAct.class);
                startActivity(obj);
            }
        },5000);
    }
}
```

Comment: ,What error r u facing ?

Comment: what is the issue you have face.

Comment: your code looks fine , whats the problem ?

Comment: In my app, everytime the app is started it goes to login page even if its logged in. I just need to open the account of the user after splashscreen if he is still logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Use **SharedPreferences** to handle login status. Like that

Make a separate MySharedPref class to store login status

```
public class MySharedPref {

SharedPreferences sharepreferences;
public static MySharedPref instance = null;

public static MySharedPref getInstance()
{
    if (instance == null) {
        synchronized (MySharedPref .class) {
            instance = new MySharedPref();
        }
    }
    return instance;
}


public void saveISLogged_IN(Context context, Boolean isLoggedin) {
    sharepreferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharepreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("IS_LOGIN", isLoggedin);
    editor.commit();
}

public boolean getISLogged_IN(Context context) {
    sharepreferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    return sharepreferences.getBoolean("IS_LOGIN", false);
}
}
```

And in Splash Activity

```
 MySharedPref mySharedPref = MySharedPref.getInstance();

 Handler handler=new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if (!mySharedPref.getISLogged_IN(SplashActivity.this)) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                 //Dashboard Activity 
                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
       finish();
        }

    },5000);
```

And remember when you login in successfully then you have to change in login class like that.

```
MySharedPref.getInstance().saveISLogged_IN(Context context, true);
```

And when Logout then

```
MySharedPref.getInstance().saveISLogged_IN(Context context, false);
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (mCurrentUser != null)  {

      // if the current user has valid serrion, then go to Around Me Activity

      Intent mainIntent = new Intent(DispatchActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
      mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
      mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
      startActivity(mainIntent);

    } else {

      // if there is no valid user session, go to Login Activity
      Intent mainIntent = new Intent(DispatchActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
      mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
      mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
      startActivity(mainIntent);
    }
  }
```

Save User ID of logged in user in shared preferences on click of login button and on splash screen handler try above code. which will check User Id Exists or not.

Answer (score -1):

As per My understanding You can do this

```
   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    activity = SplashActivity.this;
    callToHoldScreen();
}

private void callToHoldScreen() {
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            nextPageAction();
        }
    }, GeneralToApp.SPLASH_WAIT_TIME);
}

private void nextPageAction() {
    Intent intent_confirm = new Intent(activity, NewUserSelectionActivity.class);
    intent_confirm.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    intent_confirm.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent_confirm);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right,R.anim.slide_out_left);
}
```